# Netsuite - Suitescript 2.X: Inbound shipment "items" sublist update

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, clientscript

I need to update a sublist ('items') field ('receivinglocation') on inbound shipment entry.
When i create an inbound shipment from user interface, i need to update all item line locations from a body field ('customlocation').
I've tried to do that throught a Clientscript:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'],
/**
 * @param{currentRecord} currentRecord
 */
function(currentRecord) {
    
    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is saved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function saveRecord(scriptContext) {

        try {
            var lines = scriptContext.currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'items'});
            var mainLocationValue = scriptContext.currentRecord.getValue({
                fieldId: 'customlocation'
            });
            if (mainLocationValue != '' && mainLocationValue != null) {
                for (var i=0; i<lines; i++){
                    scriptContext.currentRecord.selectLine({sublistId: 'items',line: i});
                    scriptContext.currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'items',fieldId: 'receivinglocation',value: mainLocationValue,ignoreFieldChange: true});
                    scriptContext.currentRecord.commitLine({sublistId: 'items'});
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
                    log.debug({
                        title: 'Error Details',
                        details: e
                    })
        }
    }

    return {
        saveRecord: saveRecord
    };
    
});
```

But the error is always the same from the validation form:
"FAILED_FORM_VALIDATION" - "Form validation failed. You cannot submit this record"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is where your error is coming from, but you do have to `return true` from the `saveRecord()` function to allow NetSuite to save the record. You can see a note to this effect directly in the JSDoc section of the script you posted:

```
@returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
```